# How To Sort Time Data, to only showing exact clock (hh/mm/ss)?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, sorting, date-time

i want to sort my time data (there's a lot of it), to only showing data that **only** show the exact clock in hh/mm/ss format, so i can delete the unnecessary data.

for example,

from :

[image: example 1]

to only showing this result :

[image: result]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Can you edit your post and provide a sample of your data showing their differences?

Comment: Please edit and add a screenshot showing sample data as it appears now and as you would like to see it. Thanks

Comment: hi thanks for responding. i provide some screenshot to my data. hope that help

Comment: So why are you including 00:30:00 and not 23:30:00?

Comment: Do you want to filter to only show hourly and 1/2 hourly values? Your example is not clear.

Comment: im sorry i dont want the 00:30:00

i only want the exact clock

Comment: So just exact hours?

Comment: yes david, only the exact hour

Answer (score 1):

To test whether the time in a cell is an exact hour, you can use this formula (assuming your time is in cell A1):

```
=A1-TIME(HOUR(A1),0,0)=0
```

[image]

You can then filter on column B.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach, for those using Office 365, is to find the unique hours" values by using a combination of `FLOOR`, `UNIQUE` and `SORT` functions.

**FLOOR and UNIQUE functions**: This reflect the results as seen on your sample image.
[image: IMG:]

**FLOOR, UNIQUE and SORT functions**: Sort the result
[image: IMG:]